# JavaFX Container Structure Scrollpane

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

The GridPane i need for my GameBoard (Which should hold the amount of "tiles" my simulator terrain has) does not properly fit into a ScrollPane.

Shifting around the hierarchy and working with colorized containers to identify the issue was no help to fix the issue itself.

The Main Container FXML where the GameBoard is included

---

```xml
    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <items>
                        <AnchorPane>
                            <children>
                                <TextArea layoutX="1.0" layoutY="-14.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                      <ScrollPane prefWidth="800" prefHeight="500" hbarPolicy="ALWAYS" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS" >

                      <GameBoardCC fx:id="gameBoard" > 

                      </ScrollPane>
                    </items>
                </SplitPane>
```

---

The Custom Control itself:

---

```xml
<fx:root xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.221">

  <GridPane fx:id="gameBoard"
            style="-fx-background-color: green">
  </GridPane>

</fx:root>
```

---

Basically the code that adds these items, I'm pretty sure I got most of it from Stackoverflow

```java
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                // create node
                TerrainNode node = new TerrainNode ("Item " + i + "/" + j, i * 100, j *100, 100, 100);
                node.setOpacity (0.5);
                // add node to group
                gameBoard.getChildren ( ).add (node);
            }
        }
```

A Picture of the Slider Behaviour, for some reason these nodes don't get added INTO the Gridpane, but rather outside of it?

[Pictures of the Slider Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwpUg.png)

I was hoping to have the slider to be "stuck" at 50% (though this is not my main concern right now) and since my simulation is supposed to have a changeable grid size of tiles with fixed tile sizes, the scrollbars should appear at for instance 20x20 grids or in future when the client gets too small.

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I am a bit unclear with the code as you are not setting the column/row indexes to the node.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/hYWNg9K)
The aim is to have have the abillity to create a new gridpane every time i change the grid size. Every Grid Element will be represented by a value stored in a 2D Array, but i will take care of that once the GUI works fine.

Comment: Modifying `translate` properties leaves the bounds the `GridPane` considers unchanged place. What you (probably) do here is having all those bounds contained in the "cell" at (0,0) and then adjust only the position where the children are rendered. Anyway `GridPane` is usually responsible for assigning the position itself. Focus on getting the dimensions right, use the `GridPane.add(Node, int, int)` method to add the children instead of `getChildren().add(...)` And let `GridPane` deal with the rest... Btw: links (or screenshots) are insufficient ways of providing necessary code. Post text.

Comment: @fabian Thank you alot, thats basically the only change i had to do, to make it behave accordingly. You have a nice weekend! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @fabian specified, let the GridPane do its stuff. Each layout pane provided by JavaFX has a specific feature. I suggest you go through different types of layout panes and understand their basic purpose. Refer to all green boxes in below image :)
[image]

Ofcourse the layout you choosed(GridPane) is the correct one . But the execution is not correct. GridPane layouts its children based on the provided column/row indexes. You dont need to handle there layout positioning.

Below is a quick example of what the idea is like:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class GameBoardDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton size1 = new RadioButton("5 X 5");
        RadioButton size2 = new RadioButton("5 X 10");
        RadioButton size3 = new RadioButton("10 X 10");
        RadioButton size4 = new RadioButton("10 X 15");
        RadioButton size5 = new RadioButton("15 X 15");
        Stream.of(size1, size2, size3, size4, size5).forEach(rb -> {
            rb.setToggleGroup(tg);
            rb.setId(rb.getText());
        });
        GridPane options = new GridPane();
        options.setHgap(10);
        options.addRow(0, size1, size2, size3, size4, size5);

        GridPane board = new GridPane();
        board.setPrefSize(800, 500);
        ScrollPane scrollBoard = new ScrollPane(board);
        VBox.setVgrow(scrollBoard, Priority.ALWAYS);

        tg.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) val;
            double rows, columns;
            switch (rb.getText()) {
                case "5 X 5":
                    rows = 5;
                    columns = 5;
                    break;
                case "5 X 10":
                    rows = 5;
                    columns = 10;
                    break;
                case "10 X 10":
                    rows = 10;
                    columns = 10;
                    break;
                case "10 X 15":
                    rows = 10;
                    columns = 15;
                    break;
                default:
                    rows = 15;
                    columns = 15;
            }
            board.getChildren().clear();
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++) {
                for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columns; columnIndex++) {
                    Rectangle node = new Rectangle(100, 100);
                    node.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
                    node.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                    StackPane terrainNode = new StackPane(node, new Label("Item " + rowIndex + "-" + columnIndex));
                    board.add(terrainNode, columnIndex, rowIndex);
                }
            }
        });
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setSpacing(15);
        root.getChildren().addAll(options, scrollBoard);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("BoardGame");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that example, ur graphic really helped me understand the hierarchy, now its just a little more size tweaking after i'm done with the logic.
Have a wonderful Weekend!!